# Cannot ssh into Azure VM using public IP

Tags: azure

We have a Site-to-Site from our On-premise to the Azure Cloud. I added a public IP to a VM. I am able to SSH into the VM using the private IP. I want to access the public IP over the VPN & internet. I dont know what I am missing here. Please can someone help ? If I add a rule to allow Any to Any, I can access the Public IP from my network but dont want to configure it like that.

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you use Azure ExpressRoute, you can only access an Azure Public IPs over the Internet, your traffic will not traverse the VPN to reach the Public IP, it will leave your location as per any other Internet bound traffic.

As you have successfully reached the VM via the VPN, we can assume that SSH and your access itself is working fine.

Therefore you should review the Network Security Group attached either to the NIC itself or attached to the Subnet in which the VM resides to ensure it allows TCP/22 (SSH) with a source IP set to be your external IP address of your location (use something like: http://whatismyip.akamai.com/ to find out) and the destination either set to the private IP address of the VM (not the public IP) or an Application Security Group of which the VM is a member.

Comment: Thank you for your response Alex!

Comment: No problem! don't forget to up-vote and accept my answer if it helps.  Any other questions just ask.

Comment: Sorry, I did not completely respond yesterday. The rule in the NSG is present in my case. What I was trying to do as a test is that, I wanted to restrict the ssh access to the internal network and few of the external services (from Azure) so that it is not Any to Any. We found out that we can restrict the external services to our Virtual Network using the Service Tag as the source address in a NSG rule. The rule helped us give the access to the service. I am sorry for not mentioning the real problem here. Thank you for the quick reply Alex!!!